# Is ffmpeg -i input.mp4 what programmers use to get video information?

Tags: ffmpeg

Is this command what programmers use to get video information:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4
```

It seems to me like it makes you jump through hoops, since it gives you all of the information in one long string (you can't get individual information for example), and the string is not in an easy to parse format (it's not like it's key:value pairs!)

So should I use FFmpeg to get video information, or should I use some other tool?

Comment: You can do it the same way ffmpeg does: By invoking the appropriate functions on a MP4 library of your choice. It’s probably contained in `libavformat` (part of ffmpeg).

Comment: But if I decided to use an external binary, should I use FFmpeg or should I use another tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ffprobe`:

#### Basic example

```
$ ffprobe -v error -show_format input.mkv
[FORMAT]
filename=input.mkv
nb_streams=2
nb_programs=0
format_name=matroska,webm
format_long_name=Matroska / WebM
start_time=0.000000
duration=108.501000
size=56164272
bit_rate=4141106
probe_score=100
TAG:encoder=libebml v0.7.7 + libmatroska v0.8.1
TAG:creation_time=2008-10-22 06:43:30
[/FORMAT]
```

#### Duration example

```
$ ffprobe -v error -show_format -of flat=s=_ -show_entries format=duration input.mkv
format_duration="60.029388"
```

#### Notes

- You can control the output formatting with `-of`.
- Specific streams can be selected with `-select_streams`.
- You can show information about each stream with `-show_streams`.

#### Also see

- [FFprobe documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) for more options.
- [FFprobe Tips](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips) for more examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But other than the hassle of parsing FFmpeg data, is there's another reason why I should not use FFmpeg?

Comment: @Guest1564 None that I can think of, but I don't really have much info about what you're doing.

Comment: I am using FFmpeg to manipulate some video files, but I also need the information of each video file before starting the manipulation process, the problem is that FFmpeg and FFprobe are each 27 MB in size! so I don't wanna use an extra 27 MB program just to get the video file information when I can just use FFmpeg! Thank you again.

Comment: @Guest1564 You can probably compile it so it is smaller. Or just use `ffmpeg`, but parsing the output might be more annoying, and it may not be as detailed as `ffprobe`.